# Regex to word match on python

Tags: python, regex, match, cpu-word

I'm trying to create a regex for extracting the software name and the version (if exist) from a Nmap output for example :

```
ftp (product: vsftpd version: 2.3.4 ostype: Unix)
```

I applied the regex : `/product: (.*) version: (.*)/`

It gives the result :

```
group(1) = vsftpd ,  group(2) = 2.3.4 ostype: Unix
```

while I only need the version (2.3.4)

Add to that the version should be optional I tried different things but it doesn't work 
Example :

```
product: Apache Jserv extrainfo: Protocol v1.
```

As there is no version I only need the part of  `Apache Jserv '

How do i make all of this ?

Comment: Yes thank you , EDITED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN2lZ2/2):

```
product: ([\w ]+)(?:version: ([\w.]+)| \w+:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the whitespaces to solve your first issue and then use Alternation to not return version if there is none.

```
(?<=product|version):\s(\S*)
```